# Past participle form of "exit"?

Tags: verbs, orthography, conjugation, doubled-consonants

What's the past participle form of the word *exit*? Is it *exit* (irregular, like *set*)? *exited*? *exitted*? On one page I found *exited* but if that's the case why isn't it *exitted* (double *t*) like with the word *emit* - *emitted*? Is there a rule when the consonant at the end is doubled and when not?

Comment: Might have something to do with stress. *Exit* and *exited* are stressed on the first syllable; *emit* and *emitted* on the second. Similarly *ballot|balloted* (although OED admits that *ballotted* does rarely occur).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When we have a word ending in a single vowel and then the consonant 't', the consonant is only doubled before suffixes if that syllable is stressed. So when there is no stress we observe just a single 't'. In the following examples the stressed syllables are premarked with an apostrophe:

- 'rocketed
- e'licited
- 'billeted
- 'ratcheted
- 'exited

However if the last syllable is stressed then we will see a doubling of the consonant:

- ga'rotted
- 'vetted
- re'potted
- a'betted
- e'mitted

This is just a rule of thumb as there are special rules for certain prefixes, and compound words and loan words from other languages will not necessarily follow the rule.

Edit: Please also see Janus' interesting comment below about loan words with silent 't's below!

Comment: And of course if the t is purely orthographic and doesn’t represent an actual /t/, it is never doubled no matter where the stress is, so those who pronounce _ricochet_ or _debut_ with final stress would still only write one t in _ricocheted_ /rɪkəˈʃed/ and _debuted_ /deˈbjud/.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, indeed. I've directed readers to your comment! :)

Comment: Same thing with L: caroled, channeled, equaled, medaled, pedaled and penciled ***but***  compelled, controlled, dispelled, propelled and patrolled.  While “canceled” is the correct spelling according to the stress rule, it is often written “cancelled”.

Comment: @Scott Quite right, but only in US English though. The first list there all have double <l> in UK and other Englishes!

Comment: Really? We all follow the ‘T’ rule, but we split over ‘L’?  I didn’t know that.  I generally tend to ***favor***  U.S. English, but I ***realize*** more and more that it’s a bit illogical.  (My eyes hurt when I read “canceled”.) OTOH, if British English always uses double ‘L’, but uses the stress rule for ‘T’, then Br.E is inconsistent, while Am.E is at least striving for internal consistency.

Comment: Awesome. I was just having issues explaining to my spawn the discrepancies between hit/hitting, permit/permitting, and exit/exiting. I see now it's due to the first two stressing the final syllable (of the root word) HIT and perMIT, while the latter is EXit. And re " there are special rules for certain prefixes" - *damn* English with its bizarre special rules. Even as a native speaker six decades in, this still bugs the hell out of me :-)