# Why is the past tense of vomit generally spelled 'vomited' rather than 'vomitted'?

Tags: past-tense, doubled-consonants

"Vomit" is not a recent addition to English, and nor does it have a peculiar pronunciation. Yet, the past tense of vomit does not follow the notion that a vowel followed by a consonant and emphasis on the consonant. (For example, past tense of 'emit' is 'emitted'.)

Comment: Essentially any simple rule in English can be disproved.

Comment: There is no such thing as “emphasis on the consonant” in English. If that was meant to refer to stress (i.e., phonetic ‘emphasis’ on the _vowel_), then _vomit_ doesn’t do that, since the i is not stress.

Comment: This doubling (or not) of consonants with -ed, -ing, etc. ... sometimes they differ between US and UK... US traveling, UK travelling.

Comment: Because people choke on the double TT.

Comment: There are no "rules" in English.  Simple.

Comment: There are plenty of rules in English. It's just that most of them have exceptions. That's just the nature of language.

Comment: Maybe it's the t is omited?

Comment: @JollyJoker though it isn't in omitted ;)

Comment: Because it used to be, but the Assocation of Guys Named Ted objected...

Comment: Did someone tell you English is logical and tidy? If so, they were lying.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The crucial thing is that the last but one syllable of "vomited" has no stress. Not even secondary stress. So the final consonant doesn't double. By contrast, the last but one syllable of "emitted" has stress (because the last syllable of "emit" has stress).

This issue is raised in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/224397), to which a good answer is given.

Compare:

- (No stress) marketed, budgeted, edited
- (Secondary stress) combatted, formatted
- (Primary stress) patted, petted, pitted, potted, rutted

Comment: And of course, if the final consonant is silent, it’s never doubled, so it’s _debuted_, not _*debutted_, despite the fact that the second syllable has secondary stress. _Buffeted_ (ate from a buffet) and _buffetted_ (knocked, pushed) form a minimal pair in this regard.

Comment: I guess that resolves the _canceled_ vs _cancelled_ too - it is _canceled_...

Comment: @Aganju I didn't address "cancelled" because that wasn't in the question. Where the consonant is l, American and British usage differ. American leaves the l single where appropriate; British doubles it (if the l follows a single vowel) regardless of stress.

Comment: Nice answer! But: patted, petted, pitted, potted, put? After all, a (golf) putt already has 'tt'.

Comment: Whether it's a "rule" or not, as a native English speaker (with better than average spelling to begin with), I finally have a way to remember when not to double the consonant.

Comment: @eric_kernfeld Whoops! You are right. I will change that example.

Comment: @Fattie It is a 'principle that works'. Whether you choose to call it a rule or not is up to you - this answer doesn't claim as much. It may not work 100% of the time, but if it works 90% of the time, then it is useful. Claiming that we are all in the wilderness with no rules whatsoever is not.

Comment: The length of the vowel/syllable (which is related to the stress) also plays a part. Doubling the consonant is necessary (or at least usual) if *not* doubling it would produce an expected long vowel.

Comment: Nice answer! At the moment, all "primary stress" examples have two syllables, while the others have three. Would "committed" and "emitted" be examples of "primary stress" words with three syllables?

Comment: @Jake, Yes, those are good examples.

Comment: In Rosie F's answer, she suggests that 'format & formatted' are examples of Secondary stress; yet 'format' rhymes with doormat in Canada.

Comment: @Peter Not sure I understand -- "format" and "doormat" rhyme for me (BrE) too; their "a" is *not* reduced to schwa (unlike e.g. "carat" where it is). I don't see why this proves that there's a problem. For me, "formatted" has secondary stress on "mat" and non on "ted"; "vomited" has no stress on "mi" and secondary stress (albeit very slight) on "ed". How about you?